# Headlines font choices for Graphics and/or CSS Embedding?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I'm trying to identify the attached image font so we can use for artwork and web embedding.

Any other similar or better fonts for headlines will be great as well that could be used for embedding or offline graphic design?

Thank You all for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codex,

It looks very similar to Newhouse Condensed via [WhatTheFont](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/dtptypes/newhouse-dt/condensed-extra-bold/). Take a look at he 'R', it is undeniably similar with the curve at the foot of the leg.

As far as other typefaces for the web go, there are lots of other great headliners to choose  nowadays. Made possible by CSS3 (@font-face), services like [TypeKit](http://typekit.com/), and sites dedicated to web fonts like [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/). It's an exciting time for Typography enthusiasts as these new technologies and smart people who make these services provide a platform what the web has been missing for quite some time -- access to custom typefaces without much red tape.

Comment: there is also http://www.google.com/webfonts

Comment: I left Google Web Directory out only because they lack a solid selection. It's a great service and I use it on some of my sites but other than a few of their kick butt typefaces, the selection is minimal and majority of them are a bit bland. I'm sure later down the road, they'll gain more and have better, but for a better selection, TypeKit is where it's it -- even on the free tier. All I have to do now is just save up a few more bucks a month to go for a higher tier... :)

Comment: You are right. I thought of mentioning the limited selection myself. TypeKits selection is impressive. The limits are also quite OK for the free plan.